# looping through each row of snowpark/pyspark dataframe and concatenating list of dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a PySpark/Snowpark dataframe called df_meta. I want to loop through each row of `df_meta` dataframe and create a new dataframe based on the query and appending to an empty list called new_dfs. Once the looping is complete, I want to concatenate those list of dataframes. I have the below code which works fine in the case where all dataframe in the list have same columns, but it fails where the say one dataframe returns less/more columns.

```
new_dfs = []
for row in df_meta:
    database = row["db"]
    schema = row["schema"]
    table = row["src_tb_nm"]
    col_name = row["src_col_nm"]
    query = f"""SELECT {col_name} FROM {database}.{schema}.{table}"""
    new_df = session.sql(query)
    new_dfs.append(new_df)
df_out = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, new_dfs)
```

Comment: what do you want the final dataframe to look like? do you want there to be `null` values whenever there are different column values between the dataframes inside `new_dfs`?

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you have different columns in each `new_df` that you are reading in, you probably need to use `unionByName` to ensure that you can handle arbitrary column names. Since unionByName takes in two dataframes as its arguments, you'll probably need to start with the first DataFrame that's loaded, and then union with that one.

```
for i, row in enumerate(df_meta):
    database = row["db"]
    schema = row["schema"]
    table = row["src_tb_nm"]
    col_name = row["src_col_nm"]
    query = f"""SELECT {col_name} FROM {database}.{schema}.{table}"""
    if i == 0:
        first_df = session.sql(query)
    else:
        new_df = session.sql(query)
        final_df = first_df.unionByName(new_df, allowMissingColumns=True)
```